# Why does this Blade component not receive a parameter?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 9 and trying to understand the components.

I have this 'anonymous' component (extract) :

```
<option value="{{ $phase->id }}" @if(isset($phase_id) && $phase_id===$phase->id) selected @endif>
        {{ $phase->name }}
    </option>
```

The component is called like that :

```
 <x-select-phase id="phase_id" name="phase_id" :phase_id="$event->phase_id"
```

I am expecting that the var `$phase_id` exists inside the component. It is not the case, and do not understand why. I tried a lot of things without success. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#casing

> Component constructor arguments should be specified using `camelCase`, while `kebab-case` should be used when referencing the argument names in your HTML attributes.

This means:

```
:phase-id="$event->phase_id"
```

should generate a variable:

```
$phaseId
```

Comment: Good, it is written in the documentation! I just tried and it works, thanks ceejayoz